# Is there some special or secret way to get a "new document" in Preview on Mac?

Tags: mac, preview

I am trying to compare Google Docs's Drawings with Mac's Preview, and if I can have a canvas, such as a white one with 1200 x 800 pixel, then I can start drawing rounded rectangles, lines, and text.

However, there is no way to get a new blank document of 1200 x 800 pixel wide to begin drawing. Somehow it seems I have to find such an image, make a "copy" (the copy in copy-and-paste), and then "Paste from Clipboard".

Is there some special or secret method or good method to create such a new document to draw on?

Comment: Preview is not a drawing app, might be easier to use Keynote for things like that, or a dedicated application.

Comment: does Keynote actually let you draw rounded square, add line and text?  Preview actually is quite nice in drawing those items

Comment: Give it a try :-) Or create an empty PDF and use this as a template.

Comment: I concur: Preview is not a Drawing App. There are plenty of apps built specifically for  drawing, depending on what you need: OmniGraffle, Graphic, Inkscape, Affinity Designer, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what a document template on macOS is intended to do. You make one document then flag it. Next time you open it (from automation, script, recents, finder) it creates a new empty document with precisely the setup you want.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-document-templates-on-mac-mchlp1341/mac

Even though Apple documents this clearly and plainly, I suspect most people find it a “secret trick” or hidden gem once they have an itch like yours that needs scratching.

Comment: so this feature is like, if you have a file called `blank 1200 x 800.png`, then once you make it "Stationery", if you double click to open it, then that file will copy to `blank 1200 x 800 Copy.png` for you to edit, and the original file can remain un-edited. Next time if you double click that file again, the newly created file will become `blank 1200 x 800 Copy 2.png`

Answer (score 2):

There is one method:

1. simply look at any webpage with some blank space or even with content.
2. Do a screenshot by <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>, and then dragging the mouse
3. Now you have a screenshot (default location of the file is Desktop)
4. Double click it, and now you are in Preview
5. Use Preview's Tools -> Adjust Size to get your desired size. Make sure you don't use "Proportional" if you want any ratio such as 1200 x 800 or 1600 x 800
6. You can click the Drawing toolbar out, and choose a Rectangle shape, and drag the top-left and bottom-right corner to cover the whole canvas (it helps if you de-magnify to make the image smaller than the window first)
7. Choose a background color, such as white or off-white
8. Better save this file as PNG using File -> Export, and
9. Make duplicates of this file now or in the future when you start drawing

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since **Preview** can only create a new document from its **File** menu item **New from Clipboard    ⌘N**, here is a workaround suggestion.

Create an 1200 x 800 pixel graphic image in your favorite graphic imaging app and save it as e.g. **1200 x 800 Template.png** to your e.g. **Pictures** folder. Then in **Finder** select the file and press **⌘I** to show its **Get Info** *sheet*. Under the **General** *section*, lock the file, **[√] Locked** and close the **Get Info** *sheet*.

You can then open the file in any of the various ways a file can be opened.

With the e.g. **1200 x 800 Template** opened in **Preview** start editing it, something that actually makes a change to it and as as soon as you do, you'll get a message e.g.:

[image]

Then click the **Duplicate** button and you have your new document and the template is left unchanged, providing you did not unlock it.

Going forward, you'll always have the **1200 x 800 Template.png** to easily create a new document from in **Preview**.

Answer (score 1):

Some workarounds:

- Use Word online for empty PDF, https://overleaf.com etc, or any command line tool to make a PDF from LaTeX.
- Use the white box to cover all of the PDF and draw over it. But it will occasionally get selected instead of the shapes you might be drawing.
- Click a white photo, edit it in photos app and using Preview, export it as PDF.
- Take a png, Preview takes PNG as white, instead of transparent  and export it as PDF.
- **Use tools made for drawing** like https://www.sketchbook.com or photoshop or online sketchers.